# Making background image fit without cutting off/stretching image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am working on this project were i have to replace background image of the parents div when hovering each child div/columns. All the functionalities are working good except the background image i am setting is cutting off or look stretched. i have tried many examples and similar questions from stack overflow and none seems to fix the issue of stretched image or cutting off issue i have tried background-repeat and background-positioning etc.

```css
  background-image: url(https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pk8xl9lh6hl4x8/banner1.jpg?dl=1);
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

what i am i doing wrong. Here is my code in fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jaisil007/4qxh5nrz/3/

Comment: try to add :   background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 35% 65%;

Comment: in my opinion, then the appearance will improve

Comment: Do you just want the image to always be displayed in full, with the correct ratio, no matter the dimension of the containing div? Have you tried `background-size: contain` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this instead of `background-size: cover;` option.

```
background-size: 100% 330px; /* fit for the size of the div... full width and 330px height */
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see of the fiddle, it looks like the code is working fine to a point. If I resize the display pane to full size, I see the entire image. I can resize it down slowly and see that it is resizing itself as the window gets smaller, but at 767px, it stretches back out.

I would say that you probably need to have a smaller version of that image with a width of 767px, and update your max-width:768 media query to replace the original image with the smaller image.

Answer (score 0):

you try following css:

```
    background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```